# formatting one line without shifting out of center

Tags: html, css

Hi I am a beginner to HTML/CSS and especially formatting using html/css.  I was wondering if someone could help me format my line.

Right now I want to try to make the line something like

(IF # is a space)

"###Welcome###Sign In"

However when currently when I try this, it turns out to be something like

"#Welcome###Sign In"

where welcome shifts to the left when I try to put the sign in on one line.

Here is my code

```
<p class="welcome">Welcome to the Tutor Center</p>
<p class="signin">Sign In</p>

<style type="text/css">
    .welcome {
    align:center;
    }
    .signin {
    float:right;
    padding-right:10;
    }
</style>
```

This may be a very simple error but I cant seem to figure it out...

THanks

Comment: edit your question properly.This part ##Right now I want to try to make the line something like

" Welcome Sign In"

However when currently when I try this, it turns out to be something like

" Welcome Sign In"## .Both are same

Comment: Always try to add a fiddle for DHTML questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the two items to be side-by-side, but Welcome centered while Sign in is positioned right:

http://jsfiddle.net/zuLCM/3/

```
.welcome { text-align: center; }

.signin { position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This does work but how do I make the Sign in be all the way to the right.  I tried adding the float:left attribute to the .signin but that did not solve it

Comment: I think that goes back to my original question because adding the Sign In would push the Welcome out of the center.  For example if Welcome was just in there by itself

Comment: Ah, if that's the case, you'll need to use absolute positioning to take it out of the document flow: http://jsfiddle.net/zuLCM/3/

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RU6fD/

```
.welcome {
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks awesome! is there a way to put both of them in one line?